# Singularity of $\tan \frac{1}{z-2}$ at $z=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Check the Singularity of $f(z) = \tan\frac{1}{z-2}$ at $z=2$, where $z$ is a complex number.

What type of singularities $f(z)$ has at $z=2$?
We know that Singularity is mainly of two types 1) Isolated 2) Non-isolated
Again, Isolated singularity is of three types.
i) Removable singularity
ii) Pole
iii) Essential Singularity.

Now, I found that the set of singular points of $f(z)$ is
$$\left\{\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}+2 \, | \, n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \cup \{2\}.$$

Can it have both non-isolated and essential singularity at $z=2$ at the same time? It seems to be confusing to me.

Comment: essential by definition is isolated BUT NOT pole NOT removable. Hence, here, we only have a non-isolated singularity. 
By the Sokhotsky–Cazoratti theorem, 1868, for an essential singularity at $z=a$, there must exists two sequences that both converge to $a$ but their evaluated sequences diverge

Comment: Note that if there was a pole at $z=2$ then in some neighborhood of $2$, your function would have no zeros. But it does.

Comment: @Snowflake That's not what characterize essential singularities. For $f(z)=1/z$, and $a=0$ we have two sequences $(1/n)$ and $(i/n)$ both converge to $0$ and their evaluated sequences diverge, but the singularity is a single pole.

Comment: @jjagmath, then what should be the correct answer of it? I need it. Please clarify with your complete answer.

Comment: @jjagmath it holds the other way. I might have put it wrong. If it is essential, there will be sequences. not the other way round